# Xcode - calling another method inside "cellForRowAtIndexPath" and keeping the correct sequence

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

how can i call another method inside "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method and having the right sequence?

in cellForRowAtIndexPath method i have this sequence:

```
NSLog("First line");

calling another method {Method 1}

NSLog("Second line");
```

In the other method {Method 1} i have this sequence:

```
NSLog("First line in Method 1");

//Some code

NSLog("Second line in Method 1");
```

the output is:

```
NSLog("First line");

NSLog("First line in Method 1");

NSLog("Second line");

NSLog("Second line in Method 1");
```

But i want the sequence to be:

```
NSLog("First line");

NSLog("Second line");

NSLog("First line in Method 1");

NSLog("Second line in Method 1");
```

Comment: You're trying to do procedural programming when OOP doesn't work like that. My suggestion is to rework method 1 to do everything you need it to on the first call.

Comment: Can you post the actual code to illustrate the problem?